# On Local Server Working fine but once I have deployed on Live server it showing wrong IP

Tags: php

On Local Server Working fine but once I have deployed on Live server 
it showing wrong IP

```
        $ip = '';
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
        if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
            $ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
            $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ip = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
           $ip = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
            $ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        else
            $ip = 'UNKNOWN';
        return $ip;
```

Comment: If Anyone knows about this issue please reply me thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getUserIP()
{
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    return $ip;
}
```

Comment: impossible. How do you say it's wrong? My code should return the same value as http://www.mio-ip.it/ . Are you sure you aren't behind a proxy?

Comment: Sure I'm not using any proxy server and I'm also try your same code on my cloudways server now still showing wrong ip